# PDM signal demodulator CIC filter input bit width

Tags: filter, pcm

In order to convert the PDM stream into PCM samples, the PDM stream needs to be decimated.
Bits in PDM stream can be encoded as 1=> +1 and 0=>-1 and this corresponds 2bits signed number(S2.0). I use CIC decimation filter. I'm confused at this point: What should be the data type in the filter input?
[image]

I saw the following on the internet: Sign extension the PDM bits to a 8bits number before CIC or counting 1s in 8bits/16bits in PDM stream and applying this to CIC filter. Which one is reasonable?

Comment: Where is this being developed or implemented? Matlab? FPGA? DSP chip? Please give more details? The summing unit inside the CIC should not overflow more than once during any *cycle* (IIRC). So you need that many bits atleast. Please [edit] more details into the question.

Comment: I use FPGA. Doesn't fixed point mathematics have to be the same everywhere?

Comment: I think the question contains too few details to answer properly. Can you provide a link to any reference of te CIC that you are following ? What is the symbol rate of the PDM stream ? What is the bandwidth of the data encoded ? How many stages in CIC ? Why do you want to count the bits before passing to CIC ? CIC contains an integrator which is also implemented as a counter; right ? If you want to count bits before passing to CIC,  how exactly will you count ? a moving window count ? Or something else ?

Comment: "*I saw the following on the internet*" Can you provide reference links to them ?